# How to get the follow suggestions from twitter?

Tags: twitter

On Twitter there is a page that lists some users that are suggested *"Twitter accounts suggested for you based on who you follow and more."* from this link: https://twitter.com/i/#!/who_to_follow/suggestions

I didn't find an API to retrieve the same list (maybe I am missing it?).

Does anybody knows how that list can be accessed?  (other than parsing the html)

The good thing about that list, is that it is not categorized and it does contain common people (ie. not sport/cinema superstars etc.)

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? The only thing I have found is this https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/17028

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be achieved in two steps by twitter API. Seems like first you need to get the categories that twitter suggested to user, then from those categories you can get the suggested users to the authenticated user.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/suggestions

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/suggestions/%3Aslug

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the user are selected with different criteria: the one suggested with the slug are mostly celebrities, while the ones suggested by the web page are mostly common people (I think they check the people you follow and the people that follow you, or check affinity by the content posted on twitter)

Comment: It might be twitter wants to hide that information, good luck =)